# ANTLR grammar to parse nested JSON Array

Tags: antlr4

My input text is an expression written in prefix notion in JSON array. where array[0]
is operator, and any item after that is operands for operator. array can be nested, so if the one of the array items is an array, i have to evaluate that first.
example
["+", 2, 3]
["+", ["+", 1, 1], 3]

any suggestions on how to create grammar for this representation

Comment: Why don't you try yourself first? If you run into problems, you can post your grammar and ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// lexer rules:
expression:
            NUMBER
          |'[' OPERATOR (',' expression)* ']';

// parser rules:
QUOTE: '"';  
NUMBER: '0-9'+;  // not that simple
OPERATOR_PLUS: '+';  
OPERATOR_MINUS: '-';
...
OPERATOR: QUOTE (OPERATOR_PLUS | OPERATOR_MINUS | ...) QUOTE;
```

Something like that. Think about the lexers and the recursive rules.